# Javascript Object Bracket Notation Not Working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Thanks all in advance.
Going by the screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCh8j.png)

I wish to use a **dynamic variable** (**filter**) in **line 33** but it keeps throwing error. If I use the name properties of the object, Filter_M (eg: "ALL",  it works fine. If I use the the values too by using the functions (eg:
(order) => !order.completed
) directly, it works fine.
How can I resolve this?

Note: I am following similar procedure as used in MDN article. See:
[Back to the Filter Buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Client-side_JavaScript_frameworks/React_interactivity_filtering_conditional_rendering#back_to_the_filter_buttons)

A portion of my code is shown below while links to react components are shown at the bottom:

```
import React from "react";
import FilterButton from "./components/filterButton";
import MyOrder from "./components/MyOrder";

// const ORDER = [
//   { cname: 'ki', item: 'liveChicken', quantity: 0, id: "order-0", completed: true },
//   { cname: 'fu', item: 'egg', quantity: 0, id: "order-1", completed: false },
//   { cname: 'nu', item: 'chicken', quantity: 0, id: "order-2", completed: false}
// ]
// const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
// root.render(
//   <React.StrictMode>
//     <App2 orders={ORDER} />
//   </React.StrictMode>
// );


const FILTER_M = {
  ALL: () => true,
  Active: (order) => !order.completed,
  Completed: (order) => order.completed
};

const FILTER_NAMES = Object.keys(FILTER_M);

function App(props) {
    const chickenPrice = 5000;
    const [filter, setFilter] = useState('All');
    const [orders, setOrders] = useState(props.orders)


    const orderList = orders
    .filter(FILTER_M[filter])
    .map((order) => (
    <MyOrder
        item={order.item}
        quantity={order.quantity}
        cname={order.cname}
        id={order.id}
        completed={order.completed}
        key={order.id}
    />))
    
    const filterList = FILTER_NAMES.map((cname) => (
    <FilterButton
        key={cname}
        cname={cname}
        isPressed={cname === filter}
        setFilter={setFilter}
    />
  ));
}
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-fast-gw0knv)

I am expecting to display dynamically, the tasks/orders either active, completed, with all orders shown by default.

I have tried hard-coding it by using the property name or the values and it all worked out fine. But using the named variable in object (FILTER_MAP) bracket notation which is the only way of accessing named variable as name property of an object.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you are showing off but this component is not displaying anything as your not returning anything from the function shown...? Are you missing some code?

Comment: `All` !== `ALL`

Comment: Thanks @Salketer, for your interest. What I will do now is to see if I can put every bit of the code in sandbox and put it up here for everyone to see what is wrong. I have been in this for three days now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the MDN article you provided this code should work, I can't see the complete picture of your code but anyway this code below is working :

```
const DATA = [
  { id: 'todo-0', name: 'Eat', completed: true },
  { id: 'todo-1', name: 'Sleep', completed: false },
  { id: 'todo-2', name: 'Repeat', completed: false },
];


const filterBy= {
  All: (order) => true,
  Active: (order) => !order.completed,
  Completed: (order) => order.completed,
};

const DisplayList = () => {
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState('All');
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState(DATA);

  console.log(filterBy[filter]);

  const orderList = orders.filter(filterBy[filter]).map(order => (
    <li key={order.id} id={order.id}>
      <p>{order.name}</p>
      <p>{`${order.completed}`}</p>
    </li>
  ));

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setFilter('Active')}>
        view active orders ⬇
      </button>
      {orderList}
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <DisplayList />
  );
}
```

[a working sample in code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-https-z7iuhn?file=/src/App.js)

The problem is here :

```
const FILTER_MAP = {
  ALL: () => true, // HERE (ALL) is all CAPS
  Active: (order) => !order.completed,
  Completed: (order) => order.completed
};
```

and your are trying to access (All) a property that doesn't exist in FILTER_MAP

```
const [filter, setFilter] = useState('All'); // not the same as (ALL) in FILTER_MAP
```

and that is a good example of why you should use type script, because TS would have helped you find this typo.

Comment: I appreciate your support @Ahmad_Yousif. It's rather strange that hard coding it works perfectly but dynamic approach usig a named variable fails. Let me see how I can make the whole code and the components available

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-fast-gw0knv

Comment: Yousif, 
The typo was half the problem; the second part was a spelling in the prop passed down to a child component. A friend of mine looked through and spotted it.
I believe you did not see the full code on code sandbox prior to your response, else you might have spotted it too. Thanks once more